# import-im6.q16: not authorized `requests' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have installed the requests module in python 2.7 but while importing it Gives me

```
import-im6.q16: not authorized `requests' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because your script is not being executed by python, but most likely by bash.

The error you see is probably produced by the `import` executable (which is part of ImageMagick). If you try to execute, in bash:

```
$ import requests
```

You are probably going to get the same output.

---

To correctly execute your script, you need to use python:

```
$ python your_script.py
```

Or

1. you can make sure the very first line of your script is exactly `#!/usr/bin/env python`
2. Make your script executable:

   ```
   $ chmod +x your_script.py
   ```
3. Execute it without typing python in front:

   ```
   $ ./your_script.py
   ```